# Ansible Not Paying Attention to 'group' to Assign User's Primary Group on CentOS 7

Tags: ansible

I am running Ansible 2.2.0.0 to create users on a CentOS 7 server with the following:

```
- name: User creation
  user: name="{{item.username}}"
        group="{{item.username if users_create_per_user_group
            else item.group}}"
        groups="{{item.groups | join(',')}}"
        shell="{{item.shell if item.shell is defined else users_default_shell}}"    
        comment="{{item.name}}"
        uid="{{item.uid}}"
        home="{{item.home if item.home is defined else []}}"
        password="{{ item.password if item.password is defined else '!' }}"
  with_items: "{{users}}"
  tags: ['users','configuration']
```

I am assigning 'wordpress' to 'primary_group' ( so that the content developers can read and write in their wordpress area without having to worry about chgrp'ing their files ) and I see that the variable is assigned correctly in the playbook output:

```
ok: [someserver] => (item={u'username': u'someuser', **u'group': [u'wordpress']**, u'name': u'somefirstname somelastname', u'ssh_key': [u'ssh-rsa AN_SSH_PUBLIC_KEY'], u'groups': [u'someuser', u'apache', u'sftpusers'], u'password': u'A UNIX PASSWORD HASH', u'uid': 2101})
```

But the user's primary group stays 'someuser',  not 'wordpress', although no errors are generated.

Comment: There is no evidence that `users_create_per_user_group` is not `true` in your example. And `group` is `['wordpress']` here, which means that it is a list, containing one string element, and not a plain string as expected by module.

Comment: Am I wrong or is the `with_items: ...` declaration missing in the code example?

Comment: Thank you - both issues you identify were at play, users_create_per_user_group was 'true' and my use of a string versus a list was confused.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Konstantin’s thoughts:

1. Add a debug statement right before user creation to check the value of `users_create_per_user_group`

   ```
   - name: Debug users_create_per_user_group 
     debug: var=users_create_per_user_group
   ```
2. Update the user creation so that you can handle `group` as a list

   ```
   - name: User creation
     user: name="{{item.username}}"
       group="{{item.username if users_create_per_user_group
           else (item.group if item.group is string else item.group[0]) }}"
       groups="{{item.groups | join(',')}}"
       shell="{{item.shell | default(users_default_shell) }}"    
       comment="{{item.name}}"
       uid="{{item.uid}}"
       home="{{item.home | default([])}}"
       password="{{ item.password | default('!') }}"
     tags: ['users','configuration']
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear and complete solution to my question. Your example really showed me what was incorrect in my logic - especially since even though I wanted the primary group to change (be wordpress), I still wanted the individual groups to be created. I changed the statement to just check if 'item.group' was defined and, if so, to use that - i.e. group="{{item.group[0] if item.group is defined
            else item.username}}"